# Following up after informational meeting to request an actual interview

Tags: interviewing, communication, job-search, applications, email

Asking how I should write this email. Basically, I requested an informational meeting with someone to learn more about what they do. During the meeting, he introduced me to another person within the firm who has an actual job opening. After meeting with the 2nd person, the job was actually pretty interesting.

That initial meeting was 1.5 weeks ago. How do I pick it up again and officially throw my hat in the ring? Because some time has passed since the informational meeting, I don't want to come off as uninterested, disingenuous, or that I'm just shopping around.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: just to add, I followed up with a thank you email right after the meeting. They know that I am currently exploring career paths.

Comment: 1.5 weeks was probably a bit too long to wait (but better late than never).

Answer (score 2):

I think that 1.5 weeks was longer than I would have waited, but not something fatal. I would not wait any longer though. A simple way of phrasing this could be:

> Greetings Mr. Person,
>
> I enjoyed our meeting last week, and found what you do there really interesting. I am looking forward to continue the process, so if you need any other information do tell me so I can provide it swiftly.
>
> Thank you for your time,
>
> zerocent

Comment: What do you think of the following? 

Good afternoon,

I found your insights and experiences in the various functions in xxx group to be invaluable as I explore various career paths.

Thi GUy passed along a potential opportunity, which I have included below. The various strategic initiatives that he has been working on really excites me and I think it is a good fit for my skills and my aspirations. Could you please let me know how I should proceed with the application process?

Thanks in advance for your guidance.
ZeroCent

Comment: “Signed, zerocent” 

Comment: @zerocent In general it's fine. Didn't get that "Thi GUy" part. The last part, since "The various strategic..." is good. The first sentence I also would reword differently... perhaps mention your last interview as some sort of intro or something.